# Can't see reason for Compiling… Compilation failed: (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, webpacker

Deploying on `beanstalk`. Using `rails` with `webpacker`.

```
Compiling…
  Compilation failed:

  (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

We can't seem to get anymore info as to what caused the compilation fail.

How can we get more info? Is there a debug mode for beanstalk?

These are the most descriptive errors we can see:

```
Webpacker is installed  
Using /var/app/ondeck/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
Compiling…
Compilation failed:. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed.
```

Comment: What's [tag:devops] in here?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. I'm trying to install yarn on a ruby environment and beanstalk isn't providing any reason for the non-zero exit status.

Comment: Same issue here. Can you post your script? Or @KenneyE?

Comment: I'm using `react-rails` (https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and everything is working locally. For deploying, I've tried the following solutions but all of them run into the same issue as above.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/118#issuecomment-295594321

https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/additional-reading/elastic-beanstalk.md

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096244/3525808

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being that the `node_modules` directory was being created with `root` as owner, which caused permissions problems.

To figure this out, I set `webpack_compile_output` to `true` in `webpacker.yml` and then re-deployed. Doing that increases the logging output by webpacker, which revealed the problem.

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `webpack_compile_output: true` to your webpacker.yml to see more details about a failure like this. By default this is turned off.

Source: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/955#issuecomment-503830871

Answer (score -2):

You can use `eb logs` for tail logs are the last 100 lines of the most commonly used log files.

You can read more about logs here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Also ssh the machine and check/share this log - "/var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log".